# "Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=975356 in wp-db.php on line 1877" for new install

Tags: wordpress, error, installation

I am (trying to be) a new CiviCRM user.  I've tried installing both 4.7.16 and 4.6.26 on clean installs of WordPress 4.7.2.

I end up with the following error when installing the plugin.

"Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=975356 in wp-db.php on line 1877"

I can then Activate the plugin, and then I Configure CiviCRM.

"Database version and connection settings have been verified and look correct!"
as follows:

CiviCRM Database Details

Does the server exist?  OK (localhost)
Are the access credentials correct? OK
MySQL version at least 5.1  OK (MySQL 5.6.33-log)
Is auto_increment_increment set to 1    OK
Is the provided database name valid?    OK
Does MySQL thread_stack meet minimum (192k) OK
Can I access/create the database?   OK (Database 'jointe6_wp278' exists)
Can I access/create InnoDB tables in the database?  OK
Can I create temporary tables in the database?  OK
Can I create lock tables in the database?   OK
Can I create triggers in the database?  OK

Requirements

PHP Configuration

PHP5 installed  OK (PHP version 5.5.38)
MySQL support   OK
JSON support    OK
Memory allocated (PHP config option 'memory_limit') OK (512M)
File permissions

Does the webserver know where files are stored? OK ({location}/wp-admin/)
Does the CiviCRM path contain PATH_SEPARATOR?   OK ({location}/wp-admin/)
Folder 'CRM' exists?    OK
Folder 'packages' exists?   OK
Folder 'templates' exists?  OK
Folder 'js' exists? OK
Folder 'api' exists?    OK
Folder 'i' exists?  OK
Folder 'sql' exists?    OK
Is the {location}/wp-content/uploads/civicrm folder writeable?  OK

---

I click Check and Install
It reports that it was successfully installed

But the page refreshes and I get the following error:

CiviCRM Home

System Status: Error
Cron Not Running
Timestamp Mismatch
Configure Default Mailbox
Complete Setup

---

At this point, anything I try to do only shows "System Status:Error"

Any suggestions?

TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.  There was an installation of WordPress left in the public_html directory from a prior install. Removing this WP installation allowed the CiviCRM plugin installed in addon domain folders to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You're reporting two different types of errors, so let's talk about them separately.

> "Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=975356 in wp-db.php on line
>   1877"

This appears to be specific to your hosting environment - but also it doesn't appear to have affected the install of CiviCRM.

> System Status: Error Cron Not Running Timestamp Mismatch Configure
>   Default Mailbox Complete Setup

These errors are saying, "You have successfully installed CiviCRM, but it's not completely configured yet."  If you're getting these errors, you're further along than you think!

Each of those issues has to be handled differently.  Note, however, that the vast majority of CiviCRM functionality is available WITHOUT fixing these issues.  I wouldn't use CiviCRM in production without fixing those issues, but you can certainly evaluate Civi.

"Cron Not Running" means you have to set up cron.  Setting up cron isn't a CiviCRM-specific skill and unfortunately the "standard" way to set up cron requires shell (SSH) access to the server.  If you're using shared hosting, there should be a cron setup option in your control panel, but I can't give you specific instructions since there are so many different control panels out there.  You can do a search engine lookup for "civicrm cron" to find more details.

"Timestamp mismatch" suggests that either your WordPress timezone isn't correct, or there's a possible configuration issue with your hosting provider.  I would check WordPress, then raise the question with your hosting provider.

"Configure Default Mailbox" is necessary if you intend to do CiviMail mass mailings.  If not, you can select to hide this error.  Here is [documentation for mail configuration](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/advanced-configuration/email-system-configuration/), you're concerned with "outbound" configuration.

Comment: Thanks, Jon G.  I am not certain the errors are unrelated.  I am trying to troubleshoot the "Query packet" error first.  I thought it might be related to the file size uploaded being too large, so I bumped up the post_max_size and the  upload_max_filesize, but that didn't stop the error.

Comment: And I enabled error logging in in Wordpress to see what else was going on.  After running the configuration, I got the following errors logged:  "PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: alreadyInstalled in.. /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/install/index.php on line 274"  and same error on line 392.  The timezone is already correct, and I would not expect any of those errors to be fatal, yet the install is non-functional.

Comment: I just tried another hosting environment and this installs successfully.  I would prefer to use my current hosting provider, so any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this would be appreciated.